# Can I tell if a contact has used their checksum to view/change their info?

Tags: checksum

I sent out an email message to people.  I included a link with their checksum to a profile so they can review/update their info.

I can tell from the civicrm_log or civicrm_contact if they changed any of their contact info, but what if I want to know just if they visited the page even if they didn't change anything?  Or if they changed something in the profile that is a custom field which doesn't update the log or contact?

Is there something on the drupal side maybe?  The contacts don't have a drupal user.

Answer (score 2):

We set up a group specifically to track who has completed the profile and use the profile setting option to auto-add them to this group.

This way we have a group of everyone who completed the profile that we can exclude from future mailings prompting them to complete again.

This obviously won't track if someone has just visited the page, but for us, we're only interested in submissions.

Answer (score 1):

If you sent this out via CiviMail with 'clickthrough' on then you might be able to confirm who used the link with the checksum

Comment: Interestingly enough, you'd think that would do it but for some reason, it isn't recording click throughs back to our civi site.  Well, I see one, but it was just to our main site and not to their profile.  I know that at least 200 people clicked back through.

Comment: we experience the same. only external links get tracked. I wonder if that is a bug or by design.

Answer (score 1):

One thing you could do is to add piwik campaign parameters to the URL. If you use a code for your mailing as "Campaign name" and the civicrm contactid as "Keyword" you can track via piwik if people visited the page. You could also use the checksum, but that is more difficult to compare. https://piwik.org/docs/tracking-campaigns-url-builder/

With Google Analytics you can probably do something similar.